# Different/Unexpected test results using xgboost and gridsearchcv with mean square error loss

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, boosting

I'm noticing very different test results for these two sets of codes:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)
params = {'max_depth':8, 'eta':0.25, 'subsample':0.7, 'tree_method':'exact', 
          'lambda':1, 'alpha':0, 'gamma':0}
num_round = 7000
bst = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_round)
trainpreds = bst.predict(dtrain, ntree_limit=num_round)
preds = bst.predict(dtest, ntree_limit=num_round)
print(mean_squared_error(y_train, trainpreds))
print(mean_squared_error(y_test, preds))

0.12218761804574622
0.3807328933988807
```

comparing the above with gridsearchcv:

```
params = {
            'subsample': [0.7],
            'max_depth': [8],
        }

bst = xgb.XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.25, tree_method='exact', n_estimators=7000)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=bst, param_grid=params, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', 
                           n_jobs=-1, cv=5, return_train_score=True)
grid.fit(X, y)
print(grid.cv_results_['mean_train_score'])
print(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'])

-0.12729098
-3.23202986
```

I understand why we see negatives (as it is defined in Gridsearchcv docs). But I cannot understand why the mean test score is -3.23 and the hold out test set is only 0.38. Yes they are not meant to be exact, but such a large difference seems strange to me - especially considering the training score is so similar. Any ideas? Am I going wrong somewhere?

I've tried playing with the random_state parameter to see if maybe the hold out test set was unique in some way but to no avail.